# InvalidCastException when I try to add an element to an ObservableCollection in a Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, observablecollection

I'm having some issues trying to add elements to an observable collection, for my xamarin.forms app. Here you are an example of code:

```
public partial class ItemListPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> Elements { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ItemListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ElementsView.ItemsSource = Elements;
    }

    public async void OnAddButtonClicked()
    {
        string result = await GetCodeAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Elements.Add(result);
            }catch(Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }

    }}`
```

And here, there is an example of my Xaml code:

```
 <ListView x:Name="ElementsView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="PlaceHolderText" /> 
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

From the try catch section, i get an InvalidCastException, but I don't know why! Am I missing something? Should the element of an obsrvable collection, implements a specific interface? Thank you very much!

Comment: Everything seems right in the code. I don't know why it is giving an exception.

Comment: Two closing StackLayout tags, as I'm sure you're aware of now =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The child of the DataTemplate element must be of or derive from type ViewCell.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="PlaceHolderText" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```